# How order only folders by creation time using shellscript?

Tags: linux

I have some folders and files inside a directory. I need to order only the folders by creation time.

How order all folders by creation time using shellscript?
Thanks

Comment: Linux doesn't record the creation time. The "ctime" is the time of the last status change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a shell script. `ls` will order your files by creation time if you include the `-ltc` options.

From `man ls`:

> ```
> -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file 
>                   status information) 
>        with -l: show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by ctime
> ```

If you are only interested in directories and not regular files, you can filter the results by piping to `grep`

```
ls -ltc | grep ^d
```

Note: `^d` means show only lines that start with the letter `d` which in the case of the output of `ls -l` means a directories.

#### update

From [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671275/how-order-only-folders-by-creation-time-using-shellscript/4671785#4671785), it looks like you're only interested in the filename of the newest file. Try this:

```
ls -ltc | awk '/^d/{print $NF; exit}'
```

Notes:

- `/^d/` : filter lines starting with 'd'
- `print $NF` : print the last column
- `; exit` : exit immediately after the first match

Answer (score 0):

`ls -d -t`

Next time, [RTM](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not use ls in scripts; use find instead:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%C@ %f\n" | 
    sort -n | 
    cut -d\  -f2-
```

The option "-mindepth 1" is there because we don't want "." in the output.

Alternatively, you can use stat too:

```
for dir in */; do
    stat -c "%Z $n" "$dir"
done | sort -n | cut -d\  -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for all the answers!**

I got to solve my problem using the following command:

Order by Creation time:  `ls -clh | grep ^d | head -1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev`

Order by Modification time: `ls -tlh | grep ^d | head -1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev`

Comment: You can replace " | grep ..." with awk '/^d/{print $NF; exit}'